# Ng-disable not working for angularjs 1.4.9

Tags: angularjs

im using angularjs 1.4.9 for my project. can i know why ng-disable not working for this code

```
<div style="float: left">
<button ng-disabled="isDownloadQueEmpty == false" class="erg-button erg-button--large erg-button--primary erg-button--is-button"ng-click="downloadDocuments()"
style="font-size: 18px !important; width: 100%; height: 34px;"  >
Download or Email
<i class="fa fa-paper-plane" style="padding-left: 5px;font-size: 16px;"></i></button>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to bind `isDownloadQueEmpty` using ngModel. Refer to the example here https://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_ng-disabled.asp

Comment: can you create a fiddle or a runnable script here? maybe the `isDownloadQueEmpty` isn't being set to `false` when you want this action triggered.

Comment: Hi, adding type="button" to code now ng-disable is working but css part is not working. Its not dim the color on button

Answer (score 0):

Try this as follows,

```
<button ng-disabled="!isDownloadQueEmpty" class="erg-button erg-button--large erg-button--primary erg-button--is-button" ng-click="downloadDocuments()"
```